# Rails 5.2 & Ahoy 2 - "undefined method `visitor_token' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ahoy

I'm running Rails 5.2 and the awesome [Ahoy gem](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy), with mongoid as the ORM.

In the homepage controller, I'm calling `current_visit.visitor_token`, which is generating the following error:

```
MONGODB | ds111336.mlab.com:11336 | heroku_1f375nv7.find | STARTED | 
{"find"=>"ahoy_visits", "filter"=>{"visit_token"=>"4f86bf0d-f694-4a46- 
b1fb-4ff48722e5c5"}, "sort"=>{"_id"=>1}, "limit"=>1, 
"singleBatch"=>true}
MONGODB | ds111336.mlab.com:11336 | heroku_1f375nv7.find | SUCCEEDED | 
0.048124999999999994s
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 297ms (ActiveRecord: 202.8ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `visitor_token' for nil:NilClass):
```

The `ahoy_visit` value stored in the cookie is `b5b4fd64-ec42-4e6d-9740-e394ed4a24da`, yet Ahoy seems to be searching for a different `visit_token` (as above).

initializers/ahoy.rb:

```
class Ahoy::Store < Ahoy::DatabaseStore

end

# set to true for JavaScript tracking
Ahoy.api = true
Ahoy.server_side_visits = true
```

If I clear the website data from my browser (or open a new session in an incognito window), the error does not occcur until I wait another day (I'm guessing until the sessions expires).

I've searched all through the code and can not figure out why Ahoy is not creating a new visit record in the DB.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With Ahoy 2.0 you visit model need to be scoped as such

`class Ahoy::Visit < ApplicationRecord
  # code here
end`

- another walkaround is re-install Ahoy and it will place Visit and Event in the correct location.